# Moq No invocations performed

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

My unit test gives me

> "Configured setups:  x => x.GetCount(It.IsAny(),
>   It.IsAny()) No invocations performed."

This is the method below:

```
private IService Client = null;
public void CountChecks()
{
   Client = new ServiceClient();
   var _amount = Client.GetCount(value01, value01);
}
```

This is my test class:

```
public class CountChecksClassTests
{
   private Mock<IService > service { get; set; }
   private CountChecksClass { get; set; }

   [TestInitialize]
   public void Setup()
   {
      service = new Mock<IService>();
      service.Setup(x => x.GetCount(It.IsAny<DateTime>(), It.IsAny<DateTime>()));

      checker = new CountChecksClass ();            
   }

   [TestMethod()]
   public void GetCountTest()
   {
      checker.CountChecks();
      service.Verify(x => x.GetCount(It.IsAny<DateTime>(), It.IsAny<DateTime>()));
   }
}
```

When I debug the test, the method gets called. So, why am I getting a No invocations performed error? The error occurs at `service.Verify(x => x.GetCount(It.IsAny<DateTime>(), It.IsAny<DateTime>()));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every time you call `CountChecks` method - you create a new instance of `IService`, namely `ServiceClient` and assign it to your type's `Client` property, this piece:

```
public void CountChecks()
{
    Client = new ServiceClient();
    ...
```

Hence your test method never calls into a mocked instance of the `IService`, instead it calls the `ServiceClient` created internally.

In order to fix this you need to inject your mocked instance of `IService` inside your `CountChecksClass` instance, e.g.:

```
checker = new CountChecksClass(service.Object);
...
public CountChecksClass(IService service)
{
    Client = service;
}
```

And don't forget to remove `Client = new ServiceClient();` from `CountChecks` method.

Answer (score -3):

You should setup your method like this:

```
service.Setup(x => x.GetCount(It.IsAny<DateTime>(), It.IsAny<DateTime>())).Returns(/*insert count result*/);
```

Then your mock will know it's been called.

Edit: Besides, shouldn't your CountChecks method return the count value?